# Would Elasticache Redis endpoint be changed over time?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, redis, amazon-elasticache

AWS EC2 instances often have different host names and IPs over time. So in Nginx, I usually need to set a resolver to get the newest ip for current instance. Now my instance connects to a Elasticache Redis node endpoint. Would that endpoint change as well? Do I need a resolver for that redis node too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you use the endpoint (xxxxxx.amazonaws.com:6379) and not the IP to which the endpoint resolves to, you should be fine.

The endpoint only changes when the cluster gets recreated. The IP could change at any time

Answer (score 1):

The IP address may change. The DNS name does not.